# Cannot insert character into mysql column from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have following code in order to capture data from the previous page. Its working fine, the data is passing true, just the problem is the only variable that has characters ($itemName).
I simply cannot insert in mysql column. Its not type setting or character set. I suspecting its something to with a fact that the text is coming from array. Any ideas?

```
if(isset($_POST["cantidad"]) && count($_POST['cantidad'])>0) {

    foreach($_POST["cantidad"] as $key => $value) {
        $cantidad = $value;
        $value = $_POST["cantidad"][$key];
        $idItem = $_POST['hiddenField'][$key];
        $itemName = $_POST['hiddenName'][$key];
        $query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` SET `fecha` = $timestamp, `idItem` = $idItem, `nombreItem` = $itemName, `cantidad` = $value";
        ///// this section is to check do data pass true and they do
        echo "<br>";
        echo "value:" . $value . "<br>";
        echo "id:" . $idItem . "<br>";
        echo "name:" . $itemName . "<br>";

         mysql_query($query);
    }     

}

echo "<br>";
```

Comment: can you show me what the value of the `$itemName` ?
or you can try using `mysql_real_escape_string` unescaped the string.

Comment: Sure, for instance I have something like this:  Abrillantador maquina    or 7 Up 200cl

Comment: it look fine from your query. you can try this. `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` to display the error message

Comment: Hye i didnt understand the use of $value here since am a newbie in php ..is it a new variable that we create for acessing the key values ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` SET `fecha` = $timestamp, `idItem` = $idItem, `nombreItem` = $itemName, `cantidad` = $value";
```

This line is incorrect and *extremely* unsafe.  The issue is that you are not quoting your strings in the SQL query.  You need quotes around the `$itemName` value.

You also need to be escaping the values here.  This code is wide open to SQL injection.  If you use it, you will probably get hacked.

Try this:

```
foreach($_POST["cantidad"] as $key => $value) {
    $cantidad = $value;

    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["cantidad"][$key]);
    $idItem = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hiddenField'][$key]);
    $itemName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hiddenName'][$key]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` SET `fecha` = '$timestamp', `idItem` = '$idItem', `nombreItem` = '$itemName', `cantidad` = '$value'";

    mysql_query($query);
}
```

This code is *better*, but not perfect.  It's safer, but not 100% safe.

You should upgrade to using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and prepared statements ([PDO docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).

Comment: Why "insert into set", is that the right sql statement for an insert??

Comment: Didn't know about insert...set... +1

Comment: @RobertRozas: You're welcome.  Yeah, the `INSERT... SET` syntax isn't widely used, but's it's valid :-)

Comment: Thanx for a quick answer it actually worked. Im aware of security issues on this on, and I will upgraded. In any case, thanks a million, this was shamefully simple:)